# How do I transform/operate on a set/sequence?

Tags: vdm++, vdm-sl

I have a set `S = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`.

What is the syntax for changing the contents of the set (or rather, creating a new set) by applying a mathematical operation to it e.g. multiplication, power?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case for a set comprehension. So you generate f(e) for those elements of s which match a predicate p(e). The general syntax is:

```
{ f(s) | e in set S & p(e) }
```

So for example:

```
{ e*e | e in set {1,2,3,4,5,6} & e mod 2 = 0 } = {4, 16, 36}
```

There are more complex cases where you bind more than one element from the set, but this is enough to meet your example :)